# Writing a reviewed article in resume/ Statement of purpose

Tags: publications, review-articles

I am applying to several places for Masters in pure mathematics in the month of December.

I submitted a paper in a math journal and received its review. The reviewer mentions and I quote "I recommend
this article for publication". However, he has suggested to make some changes and upload a revised version. I am working on the changes but it may take a while and the next review might take more time and thus cross the application deadlines.

Now for university applications, I want to ask what can I write in my CV/SOP to show the current progress as in it is almost sure that it will be accepted and writing just submitted doesn't show the actual situation. Also, writing accepted will be wrong as it isn't accepted yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cite articles "in preparation" or conference presentations in post-doc/junior positions grant application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/95356/cite-articles-in-preparation-or-conference-presentations-in-post-doc-junior-po) see also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/100025/undergraduate-resume-for-phd-application-include-publication-in-preparation and https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7549/should-i-post-publications-in-preparation-or-just-submitted-on-my-cv and some more...

Answer (score 1):

I don'n know about pure math, but I have seen faculty in science and engineering departments, having "published", "in press", "in preparation" articles in their cv. Your article is in a state further than what is understood "in preparation". Mentioning it in your statement of purpose/cv is quite OK.

Comment: Can you suggest something on how should I mention it? 
Should I write something like - "Received a positive feedback from the reviewer and currently under revision"

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to refer to the status is "in preparation" or "under review" in the citation. You could also specify in text that it received a "revise-and-resubmit" decision and you are revising.

Comment: Sounds more like "minor revisions".